# Trie tree struct declaration

Tags: c, struct, tree

so I've this piece of code (which is not mine) and I can't understand for the life of me what those structures look like. Can someone explain please?

```
typedef struct trie_node trie_node_t;
struct trie_node
{
    int value;
    trie_node_t *children[ALPHABET_SIZE];
};

// trie ADT
typedef struct trie trie_t;
struct trie
{
    trie_node_t *root;
    int count;
};
```

Int count in second struct is for counting all words put in the tree, but I would like to know how many times every single word was put in there, and apart from modifying rest of the code, how should I modify the structure to achieve that?

Rest of the code: http://pastebin.com/9zQuCBjb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are familiar with the concept of a trie, where you find words and prefixes of words by walking (or crawling, to use the words of the linked code) down the tree with the letters of the word and branching at each node according to the letters you find. Each node has many children; 26 if you use the case-insensitive Latin alphabet.

The word is encoded in the path on which you get there:

```
root->[f]->[i]->[s]->[h]  --> "fish"
```

Now you need to know whether the current node represents a word. `"fish"` is a word, but `"fis"` isn't. You can't use the fact that the node is a leaf without children, because `"fishbone"` might be in the dictionary. That's what the `value` entry is for: Zero means the current node does not represent a word, otherwise the value is a one-based index of the current word.

When you create a new entry, you just crawl down the trie, possibly creating new nodes as you go and marking the last node with the current count fo words as value. If `"fishbode"` is already in the trie and you add `"fish"`, you don't create new nodes and only mark the `"h"` node with a new value.

The `trie` struct is just a helper to contain the trie's root node and a count.

If you want to keep track of occurrences, add a `count` field to the nodes and increment it whenever you set `value`. (The original code doesn't check whether a value is already in the trie before and adds words unconditionally, thereby overwriting any old values.)

You can also keep a count of all words starting with the prefix at the current node by having an `prefix_count` field and incrementing that whenever you pass a node when inserting a key.

When you want to retrieve the occurrencs, you'll have to walk all subtrees.

Tries are useful for autoexpansion of words from the first letters of user input or T9-style typing systems, but they are rather memory greedy. If you just want to count the occurrences of words (without making use of the benefits of a trie), it might be easier to achieve this with a single hash map of word to count.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind If I ask 2 more questions? First, void insert function and "  trie_node_t *pCrawl; pCrawl = pTrie->root;" What does that mean? And then at the end, pCrawl->value = pTrie->count; I don't understand at what point pCrawl became our tree

Comment: There's only one trie, but many nodes. At the beginning, there is one node in the trie, created in `initialize()`. Then you walk down the trie, the `level` is the level of descent (not counting the root) which is also the index in your string. Walking down is done by `pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];`. It's like `p = p->next` in a linked list, only that here, each node has 26 children, some of them `NULL`. That's what I tried to show in my sketch with the bracketed letters. (The code does not check the range of the `CHAR_TO_INDEX` conversion and assumes that the char is an upper case letter.)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now. So to add what I want I should add "int counter" to typedef struct trie_node trie_node_t; and at the end of void insert, after the loop and before the last line insert something like "if(pCrawl->value!=0) pCrawl->counter++ else set it to 1;" right? edit: It works :D Now I have to figure out a couple of other things, like how to alphabetically print all those words and find 100 with highest number of repetitions.